# Invalid arguments were passed to DockerOperator (retrieve_output)

Tags: docker, airflow, dockeroperator

In trying to create the DockerOperator, I got this error:

```
 Invalid arguments were passed to DockerOperator (task_id: t2). Invalid arguments were:
**kwargs: {'retrieve_output': True, 'retrieve_output_path': '/tmp/script.out'}
```

Here is my code:

```
from airflow.decorators import task, dag 
from airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker import DockerOperator

from datetime import datetime

@dag(start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1), schedule="@daily", catchup=False)
def docker_dag():

    @task()
    def t1():
        pass

    t2 = DockerOperator(
        task_id='t2',
        container_name="task_t2",
        image='stock_image:v1.0.2',
        command='python3 stock_data.py',
        docker_url="tcp://docker-proxy:2375", # I have to use this on MacOS or I'll get a Permission Denied error
        network_mode='bridge',
        xcom_all=True,
        retrieve_output=True,
        retrieve_output_path="/tmp/script.out",
        auto_remove=True,
        mount_tmp_dir=False
    )

    t1() >> t2

dag = docker_dag()
```

Note: Here is [the link to the documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker/index.html#airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker.DockerOperator) which shows my arguments do exist in the documentation. So why would I be getting an InvalidArgument error for just these 2 specific arguments?

Comment: Which Airflow and which Docker provider version are you using? Long shot [but those parameters](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/15330) were added in October 2021 (I think Docker provider 2.2.0), so just double checking if you have an old version pinned somewhere.

Comment: @TJaniF you are a genius! I was using apache-airflow-providers-docker==2.1.0.

Comment: Haha thank you! I'll add my comment as an answer for visibility. And not a genius I just used git blame on the relevant lines in the source code 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`retrieve_output` and `retrieve_output_path` were added to the DockerOperator in the Docker provider version 2.2.0. :)